# ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize

I´m new to programming. I´m trying to use scipy minimize, had several issues and gotten through most of them.

Right now this is the code, but I'm not understanding why I´m getting this error.

```
par_opt = so.minimize(fun=fun_obj, x0=par_ini, method='Nelder-Mead', args=[series_pt_cal, dt, series_caudal_cal])
```

Answer (score 10):

Not enough info is given by the OP, but basically somewhere in the code it's specified to operate by data frame column (axis=1) on an object that is a Pandas Series. If the code typically works but occasional gives errors, check for degenerative cases where a data frame may have only 1 row. Pandas has a nasty habit of guessing what you want -- it may decide to reduce a 1-row data frame to a Series (e.g., the `apply()` function; you can disable that by using `reduce=False` in there).

Add a line of code to check the object is `isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)` or else convert the offending pandas Series to a data frame, something like `s.to_frame().T` for the problems I had to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.DataFrame(df)` before your `so.minimize` function.

Pandas wants to run on DataFrame for that function.