# No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dataframe, indexing

I created a DataFrame and I am trying to sort it based on the columns. I used the below code.

```
frame.sort_index(axis=1)
```

But this is causing the below errors

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-93c925b11670> in <module>()
----> 1 frame.sort_index(axis=Integer(1))

/ext/sage/sage-8.4_1804/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in sort_index(self, axis, level, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position, sort_remaining, by)
   4455                                     inplace=inplace)
   4456 
-> 4457         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   4458         labels = self._get_axis(axis)
   4459 
/ext/sage/sage-8.4_1804/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in _get_axis_number(self, axis)
    373                 pass
    374         raise ValueError('No axis named {0} for object type {1}'
--> 375                          .format(axis, type(self)))
    376 
    377     def _get_axis_name(self, axis):
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: you want to sort it based on which column?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269973/valueerror-no-axis-named-1-for-object-type-class-pandas-core-series-series? Can you add your frame, or one that exhibits the same behaviour?

Comment: @AllaTarighati, This is the frame that I am creating                                      
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape((2, 4)),index=['three', 'one'],columns=['d', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DataFrames, the value to be passed for axis is `columns`.

```
frame.sort_index(axis='columns')
```

Comment: So you wanted to reorder columns based on column names?