# What does this mean - ValueError: No axis named -1 for object type DataFrame

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to enter my own data set into a NN for wind speed forecasting.
Everything seems to be correct, but I get this error message:
ValueError: No axis named -1 for object type DataFrame

What does this mean?

Comment: You need to give us some code to know what's going on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649160/no-axis-named-1-for-object-type-class-pandas-core-frame-dataframe)

Comment: @ohtotasche There are 800 lines of code. Which part do you need to see?

Comment: @Hagbard. No, not really.

Comment: I would say at least the line that throws the error. In general, the recommendation is to create a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: @ohtotasche I am not sure which line is throwing the error. I have axis=-1 in three lines like this: sample_losses = np.mean(np.abs(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1) sample_losses = np.mean(sample_losses, axis=-1) sample_losses = np.mean((y_true - y_pred)**2, axis=-1)

Comment: The axis parameter makes sense if you have a np.array, but you are passing a DataFrame into np.mean, so I don't think it's going to let you use -1. If you already have the data in a DataFrame, you might also consider using DataFrame.mean().

Comment: "*There are 800 lines of code. Which part do you need to see?*" - please see how to create a [mcve]. The error message itself comes with an indication of *where exactly* it has happened.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have much to go on, but I'm guessing you can't use the DataFrame however you are trying to use it.  For instance, this works:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.mean(a,axis=1), np.mean(a,axis=-1)
```

This does not and throws the error you mention:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])})
np.mean(df,axis=-1)
```

If you want a mean of a Series in a DataFrame, you may want to be looking at `DataFrame.mean()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.